# Signal values peaks and noise reduction

Tags: atmel, signal-processing, atmel-studio

I have a stream of signal values (e.g. 10, 12, 13, 11, 15, 12,500, 10, 23, 25, 30, 200).

As you see, some noise like the values 500 and 200 exist on the stream.

**How can I eliminate this noise or reduce it?**

The peaks are detected using a fixed threshold value (e.g if the signal value +/- 50, then this value is a peak).

**My Algorithm is:**

I tried to make a mask with 10 values and then calculate the average of it, through sloping this mask on the whole stream, i can substitute the peaks with the mask average and then shift the mask by one value.

***are there any other algorithms to solve the issue?***

**Evaluation**
My Algorthim is still influenced by the value of the peaks (of course) and also if several peaks are near to each other( like :  500,600,650,510,.. , 10,50)  so the mask average will be big relatively to the other averages.

***are there any solution for this problem ?***

Comment: There are many algorithms to attack noise in a sequence of samples.  To know which is appropriate, you have to explain more about the type of noise, any correlation it has to real values, what sequence you would like to see out of this magic filter for the values above, etc.  Without that, this question is way too vague.

Comment: i edited my question and gave a several examples. please unhold my question !!

Comment: I believe you can solve your problem by applying a [median filter](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/10/median-filtering/)

Comment: This is neither about specific electronics design problem, electromagnetic forces, communication scheme nor firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications. It is about signal processing and as such it belongs to Signal Processing.

Answer (score 1):

A low-pass filter could work for you.

Depending on the application, this could be as primitive as a rectangular filter, where you replace each value by the average of the five values around it, or you could add a weight to individual values.

You could experiment with different filter kernels:

- [ .2  .2  .2  .2  .2 ] (equal weight)
- [ .1  .2  .4  .2  .1 ] (no negative weights)
- [ .2 -.3 1.2 -.3  .2 ] (better peak suppression)
- [ .1  .2  .3  .3  .1 ] (asymmetric)

etc.

Comment: Note that your filters have energy > 1... to reduce complications, use normalized filters (energy=1)

Comment: thanks alot . i already tried this idea, works fine. but if several peaks are near to each other( like : 500,600,650,510,.. , 10,50) so the mask average will be big relatively to the other averages.